# Navigating up and down divs in a grid (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, dom, math

Take this 9x9 grid composed of divs:

[image: original grid]

Now, let us remove some squares:

```
$('.sq-15').fadeOut(400, function(){
   $(this).remove(); // etc
});
```

Result:

[image: grid with removed squares]

How can I, from one square, select the square on TOP of it? Or for the sake of it, the BOTTOM square?

When I have the original grid, it is easy: just go back 9 divs to select the div above it. Or navigate 9 divs ahead to select the bottom one:

```
$('.sq-15').prevAll().eq(9);
```

The tricky part comes when some divs are removed -> how do I know how many steps to go until I select the div above? Am I heading in the wrong direction?

The markup can for example look like this:

```
<div data-color='#FFC20A' data-sq='0' class='sq sq-0' style='background:#FFC20A;'>
</div>
<div data-color='#FFC20A' data-sq='1' class='sq sq-1' style='background:#FFC20A;'>
</div>
<div data-color='#66CC33' data-sq='2' class='sq sq-2' style='background:#66CC33;'>
</div>
```

Comment: Do it in something other than html and css with divs! If you named your div's like cells and rows would that help?

Comment: I would like to see more complete markup with some div's removed.  Does the # in "data-sq" have gaps for removed items, or are they always exactly in sequence.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you switch the logic to having the grid data in JavaScript and using HTML+CSS to represent it instead of trying to deduce the data from the HTML presentation.

Comment: Yeah, Juhana and Toby, you're both pointing in a different but more convenient direction.